# How does a client know whether to make a request to localhost in dev mode or make a request to named server in production mode?

Tags: http, web, server, client, client-server

I'm trying to understand how a web client and a server connect and how those connections are handled in dev mode versus production mode.

The part that I am having trouble wrapping my mind around is how to differentiate making a request to localhost from the client as opposed to making a request to a server that is in production (hosted on Heroku for example).

I know how the client makes a request to the API, but how does the client know whether to make a request to localhost:3000 in dev mode or to a different URL in production mode.

My idea of production mode is that the server is hosted (by Heroku for example) and therefore can no longer be queried at localhost.

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost always handled through configuration (e.g., *.properties) files that are different for each environment.  The difference is usually handled in the build (selecting different properties files for build artifact) or by passing arguments or environment variables to the application when it is started.

Comment: Makes sense! Could you please provide an example?

Comment: I don't understand the need for an example - your question is abstract so the answer is abstract as well.  The details always depend on implementation decisions and the platform involved.